# mysql auto-increment; incorrect number sequence after deleting some rows

Tags: mysql

My table has a `AUTO INCREMENT` primary key field. In the `phpmyadmin` homepage when I click on my database, it shows I have `3663` records in my table. But when I opened my table, I found out that serial no (the `AUTO INCREMENT` field) 3824 is going on.

I had deleted a couple of rows from the table, and since then the problem started. How do I fix the `AUTO INCREMENT` field now?

Comment: There is nothing to fix. The value of a generated primary key is meaningless. Gaps are expected and are not a problem.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. This must NOT be fixed. If you need in continuous enumeration then add separate column for this purposes.

Comment: What do you mean @Akina? There will be two primary key fields?

Comment: No, the column with continuous enumeration won't be PK. Moreover, it can be not indexed at all.